# Post request with host = "><script>alert('qualys_xss_joomla_2.5.3')</script>

Tags: web, hacking

On my web server
Yesterday I have caught a `POST` request with following text for a `host`

```
"><script>alert('qualys_xss_joomla_2.5.3')</script>
```

in full it was like this

```
headers
{
  ...
  "host": "%22%3e%3cscript%3ealert('qualys_xss_joomla_2.5.3')%3c%2fscript%3e",
  "x-forwarded-port": "443",
  "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
  ...
}
httpMethod
POST
```

Is it a hacking attack? What was it aimed for?

Comment: Do you have a client who'd be likely to run a security scan on your site? Qualys is a reputable, paid tool; you wouldn't typically see it used by someone malicious, there are other tools for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone's (using https://www.qualys.com/) scanning your site for XSS vulnerabilities (and looking for a particular known vulnerability in Joomla, it looks like). See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) for details on how XSS works and how you can protect yourself.